# Spacewalk error: jabberd/c2s[4642]: SASL callback for non-existing host: a.b.c.d

Tags: xmpp, spacewalk

I am running spacewalk 2.6 on CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

and on starting spacewalk with spacewalk-service start

I observe:

```
jabberd.service - Jabber Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jabberd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2018-02-28 16:24:06 UTC; 7h ago
  Process: 4644 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4644 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/jabberd.service
```

Upon further investigation, and googling

```
#journalctl -xe
Mar 01 00:21:58 gss-spacewalk-1-prod.aws.a.b.c jabberd/c2s[4642]: SASL callback for non-existing host: spacewalk.a.b.c
Mar 01 00:23:13 gss-spacewalk-1-prod.aws.a.b.c jabberd/c2s[4642]: [25] [::ffff:1x.1xx.1xx.82, port=46909] connect
Mar 01 00:23:13 gss-spacewalk-1-prod.aws.a.b.c. jabberd/c2s[4642]: [25] [::ffff:1x.1xx.1xx.82, port=46909] disconnect jid=unbound, pac
Mar 01 00:23:13 gss-spacewalk-1-prod.aws.a.b.c. jabberd/c2s[4642]: SASL callback for non-existing host: spacewalk.a.b.c.
```

now spacewalk.a.b.c seems to be an aws load balancer:

```
$nslookup spacewalk.a.b.c
Server:         1x.xx.xxx.80
Address:        1x.xx.1xx.80#53

spacewalk.a.b.c canonical name = internal-GSS-Spacewalk-123456789.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
Name:   internal-GSS-Spacewalk-123456789.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 1x.1xx.1xx.55
Name:   internal-GSS-Spacewalk-123456789.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 1x.1xx.1xx.82
```

I have searched forums and blogs, but cannot find a resolution of this jabberd not starting

--------------- answer to @tukan ------------------------------------

There are actually 6 programs that run when jabberd is started. Their executable are located in the following locations:

```
1. /usr/bin/c2s 
2. /usr/bin/jabberd 
3. /usr/bin/resolver 
4. /usr/bin/router 
5. /usr/bin/s2s 
6. /usr/bin/sm

jabberd configuration:

1. /usr/bin/c2s -c /etc/jabberd/c2s.xml        https://pastebin.com/A1Qp44qp
2. /usr/bin/jabberd itself does not have a config ??
3. /usr/bin/sm -c /etc/jabberd/sm.xml          https://pastebin.com/4gi4MR3g
4. /usr/bin/router -c /etc/jabberd/router.xml  https://pastebin.com/cdRZqk5D
5. /usr/bin/s2s -c /etc/jabberd/s2s.xml        https://pastebin.com/nPsMsde3
6. /usr/bin/sm -c /etc/jabberd/sm.xml          https://pastebin.com/s7vQu3VE

c2s and sm are configured to encrypt information that passes through them. The cert and key used to do this are located in the /etc/jabberd/server.pem file.

ports:
[root@gss-spacewalk-1-prod jabberd]# nmap -sT -p 5200-5400 localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-03-09 19:11 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00022s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 198 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5222/tcp open  xmpp-client
5269/tcp open  xmpp-server
5347/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
[root@gss-spacewalk-1-prod jabberd]#  netstat -nl | head
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20048           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36536           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25151         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

---------------------Firewall Config ---------------------------------------

```
# service iptables status
iptables: Firewall is not running.
# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Comment: Could you show us your *jabberd* configuration?  Could you show us the running ports on the *Centos*?

Comment: @tukan i updated the question space to answer your question due to ( space and format limitation in comment section )

Comment: Great and your firewall config?

Comment: @tukan firewall and SElinux Status added ^^

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the configurations.  Your configuration looks fine to me.  You have only lowercase in your configuration files.

I think you still may be hitting the uppercase host name:

`internal-GSS-Spacewalk-123456789.us-east`

as your `nslookup` gives you capital letters in your name

> $nslookup spacewalk.a.b.c Server:         1x.xx.xxx.80 Address:
>   1x.xx.1xx.80#53
>
> spacewalk.a.b.c canonical name =
>   internal-GSS-Spacewalk-123456789.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. Name:
>   internal-GSS-Spacewalk-123456789.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com Address:
>   1x.1xx.1xx.55 Name:
>   internal-GSS-Spacewalk-123456789.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com Address:
>   1x.1xx.1xx.82

Try it your FQDN all lowercase and it should start working. I'm now writing on mobile, I'll fill in the references later when I'm on notebook.

**Edit** As promised here are the sources:

[If hostname contains upper and lower case the communication between jabberd and osad/osa-dispatcher fails](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=528145)

To quote:

> "NEVER use UPPERCASE letters in the Satellite hostname, things just
>   don't work! "

[Problem installing Spacewalk on CentOS7 (Brand new install)](https://www.redhat.com/archives/spacewalk-list/2017-December/msg00021.html)

As weird as it sounds, you should never use uppercase in your hostname!